# Choose DC server to active directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, directoryentry

in our company we have 3 DC servers (2003 server).

before couple days, we add new DC server (2012 server).

our code, uses the old dlls to get Active Directory data (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry).

our code don't call to a specific DC server. the code uses the current Active Directory server of the server that host the application.

in code:

what we are using:

```
DirectoryEntry ad = new DirectoryEntry();
```

so, when the LDAP choose the new DC server, we get an exceptions.

and we need to restart the server that host the application until he will not choose the new DC server.

how can we tell to the DirectoryEntry object don't chose the new DC
without changing and compiling the code?

is there any configuration file?